# Finding out what boots on startup for Raspberry Pi/Linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, autostart

apologies for the long question, but I need to be as specific as possible.

I am creating a project that allows me to control the functionality of a camera with a remote control. This project is run from a Python program, and pipes its output into another program, called chdkptp (which is the program that allows me to control the camera). A little bit ago I was trying to figure out how to get this project started on bootup (so I could plug my Raspberry Pi in, and have everything working without the need of the desktop). I tried a couple different things (such as adding the command I wanted to the rc.local file, etc), but ended up adding an autostart to

```
~/.config/autostart
```

and this is what's inside of the file I made:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Terminal autostart
Comment=Start a terminal and boot remote_function.py piped into chdkptp.sh
Exec=/usr/bin/lxterm -e 'cd chdkptp-r735 && ./remote_function.py|./chdkptp.sh'
```

Basically this opens lxterm and executes the command that I need to start up my python program that pipes its output to chdkptp, and this works.

**But my question is this:**
I believe I may have accidentally started my Python program in a different location while trying to figure out what I needed to do **because my python program boots up twice**. I know this because I have an LED flash once when the program is up and running, but it flashes twice and I cannot figure out where else I had my program boot up. How do I go about figuring this out?

I may already have an answer, but don't know what it means... I typed this command suggested by someone:

```
ps -ax | grep 'remote_function.py'
```

and got this response:

```
875 ?        S      0:00 xterm -class UXTerm -title uxterm -u8 -e cd chdkptp-r735 && ./remote_function.py|./chdkptp.sh
1026 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 bash -c cd chdkptp-r735 && ./remote_function.py|./chdkptp.sh
1028 pts/0    S+     0:00 python ./remote_function.py
2169 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto remote_function.py
```

Is this the answer? If so, what exactly does this mean? Does it have anything to do with the shebang at the beginning of my python program? I am a a newbie when it comes to that. If that is not the answer, how to I go about finding where else my program is starting on bootup?

The shebang is this, for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: First I'd like to ask the obvious .. Is there any way that your programming could be the culprit in flashing the LED twice?  Second have you checked the PID list to see if there are two instances of your program running?

Comment: @Zak I have tested simply executing the python program not on bootup, and when I do this, the LED flashes only once, leading me to believe it is a startup issue. Apologies if this is a dumb question, but how do I go about checking the PID if two instances are running?

Comment: You can use `top`  --  I personally use `htop` as it's a little more rubust: `sudo apt-get install htop`  And just issue the command `htop`  --  You'll be able to filter by process name ..

Comment: @Zak okay, I did that and filtered Python, and yes... two instances are indeed running

Comment: OK .. During startup .. Do you "see" other processes duplicated?  IE:
`Starting Apache2`
`Starting Apache2`

Comment: I do not see any other processes being duplicated

Comment: @Zak if you look at rm-vanda's answer, I commented what I get when I search the PID to see what's running them. They look identical and I seriously cannot figure out why this is being booted up twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I figured it out.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=59285

I have been connecting to my raspberry pi with VNC, and I had an autostart command along with my remote_python autostart to start the VNC server so I could remote in to my pi without needing a monitor. Turns out there is some sort of bug with the VNC Server that starts things up twice. Of course. I am using an x11 VNC server instead and now things are only booting up once :)

Answer (score 0):

You do, in fact, have two processes running your python script.

Finding out what started the second may not be very fun, but since you can see that the second one is started with `python ./remote_function.py` then you have two clues:

First, in order for that^ to work, it would have to be in the same folder as your `remote_function.py` - perhaps you remember tinkering with something that started it by itself in that^ way?

Second, you may be able to find the location of the file that holds that^ via `sudo grep 'python ./remote_function.py' ~` - but since it calls it with `./` - it should be pretty plainly obvious (unless you have copies of that file scattered about - which may be the case.

Comment: Yes, trying to figure out what else is starting my program is extremely frustrating :( but when I call 'sudo grep 'python ./remote_function.py'' ~ all I get is: 'grep /home/pi: Is a directory'

Comment: If you look [here](http://imgur.com/7vjkCQQ) you can see at the bottom of the picture that I ran htop to see the PIDs of both instances of the python program, and both of them seem identical. Does that mean anything?

Comment: that is a touch strange - 
how about a sanity check? If you disable the run on boot, does the LED blink at all? What if you add a little snippet that appends to a file when the script is first run?

Comment: Also, to answer this other question of yours I just happened to notice - (and is currently on hold) - `chmod -x /path/to/your/remote_function.py` - and if you're really in a hurry to get this solved, you could always have the script write to a file on startup, erase the file on it's closing - and check to see if that file exists to see if it should even run or not. 
i.e. 
`if os.path.isfile("functionStarted"): 
   exit();
else: 
   open("functionStarted", 'wb').write('True, whatever').close();`

Comment: Very strange. Let me test everything after disabling the /.Config/autostart file and see what happens. How should I go about adding the little snippet you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I disabled the run on boot, and then rebooted.... Nothing happened. My program did not boot. So I should have checked that first. So it seems that my autostart is the culprit, but I don't necessarily know where to go from here...